# Identify programmatically if the ant task has been completed

Tags: java, ant

I have a class that creates an Ant Java task programmatically, using the following code :

```
        Project p =  new Project();
        Target t = new Target();
        t.setName(this.clientName);
        p.addTarget(t);

        Java java = new Java();
        java.setProject(p);
        java.setClassname("com.testing.Test");
        java.setTaskName("Testing Java Task");

        t.addTask(java);

        p.executeTarget(this.clientName);
```

I need to know when the Target ***t*** has finished executing the task.

Comment: since you are not using `java.setFork(true)` your `p.executeTarget()` will finish executing after `t` has finished executing (if you are not using `thread`s in `com.testing.Test`)

Comment: As I don't have definitions of Project and Target class. I can suggest only a workaround to check if Ant task is finished or not.  I would suggest at the end of ant task create a temp file and check for temp file existence using java.